# Reactivemongo parseURI is failing when loading from config saying it can't find implicit value for parameter loader MongoConnection.ParsedURI

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to use the reactivemongo driver in my play application without using the play module for reactive mongo.

So when I try and get the parsedURI from my config, I am getting the below error:

```
import reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection.ParsedURI
import reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver
import com.typesafe.config.Config


val driver = new AsyncDriver(Some(config.get[Config]("mongodb")))
val parsedUri = config.get[ParsedURI]("mongodb.uri")
```

Error message:

> could not find implicit value for parameter loader:
>   play.api.ConfigLoader[reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection.ParsedURI]
>   [error]     val parsedUri = config.getParsedURI
>   [error]                                          ^ [error] one error
>   found

My application.conf has:

```
mongodb {
  uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb"
  mongo-async-driver = ${akka}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigLoader` is a `Play` type class (like `Reads`) which tells play how to read a type from the config file.

You can find an explanation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaConfig#ConfigLoader

Generally you would define this by doing something like:

```
// Config
{
  config {
    url = "https://example.com"
  }
}

// Config class
case class AConfig(url: String)

// Config Loader
implicit val configLoader: ConfigLoader[AConfig] = ConfigLoader {root => key =>
  val config = root.getConfig(key)
  AConfig(config.get[String]("url"))
}

// Usage
val aConfig = config.get[AConfig]("config")
```

In this case I would not suggest attempting to make one for `ParsedURI` because it is quite a complex type. Instead I would suggest doing something like:

```
val parsedUri: Try[ParsedURI] = MongoConnection.parseURI(config.get[String]("mongodb.uri"))
```